# How to locate the file where @import font is placed

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

Im trying to optimize my site for speed and in the waterfall I see a font family being called (lato), I have not been able to locate where in the files it is placed. Any idea how I can find the line of code so I can delete it?

Site is https://cogent.fi/ and here is the report https://gtmetrix.com/reports/cogent.fi/tuwDUf8g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your backend files, it is hard to say 100% where the font is coming from, but it looks like you are using Wordpress. I would check the header file for any extra code. If you do not see it there, sometimes some starter themes have that font in the functions.php file, or somewhere similar to that.

For example, the popular Bones Wordpress theme includes it hidden deep into the functions file. See this link for the exact spot for reference, via their github repo.

https://github.com/eddiemachado/bones/blob/master/functions.php#L242

I would open the base folder with all your files into a text editor, I use Sublime Text, and do a search in all the files for the keyword, 'lato'. I think that will help you find it pretty quickly!

Good luck! If those tactics don't work let me know, I may be able to help further.

Comment: Thanks brad. The function and header files where all empty, just my own GTM codes where added to the header. Ill give sublime a shot. I have it, but never thought it would be useful for this case! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[Lato](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato) is a Google font.

You can see the resource being requested by your website if you use Chrome dev tools too.

In the picture above you can see that is requested from the index page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Im using a theme in wp and the index file being a php, that does't include the usual html stuff (im more familiar with) things get a bit more tricky for me. I can't just look at the "page source" :) I see the ebor-lato-font-css and have not yet found that file on the server. (im using transmit for mac) where the search function doesnt sweep the directories. I guess it's in the ebor-theme-style? but have not found that one either. Im going to continue my search :) thanks any way.